# Find $\min(\operatorname{trace}(AA^T))$ for invertible $A_{n\times n}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, trace

For invertible $A_{n\times n}$ find $\min(\operatorname{trace}(AA^T))$

(a) $0$
(b) $1$
(c) $n$
(d) $n^2$

Clearly for $A=I$, it is $n$, and I am unable to get any lower values, but how do I prove it.

Comment: Well if you take $\varepsilon\cdot I_n$ for small $\varepsilon$ then you get a lower value, to begin with.

Comment: and in that way you get all positive values for the function. Since it only takes positive values, this gives you the answer.

Comment: If $A$ is real, there is no minimum value. As Mariano mentioned, if you compute the $i$th diagonal entry of $AA^{T}$, this is the norm squared of the $i$th row of $A$ and is hence positive. Thus, the trace is positive. But Ian's answer shows that you can make the trace as close to 0 as you like.

Comment: If the entries must be integers, $n$ is correct.

Comment: Well thanks to all of you. This is a multiple choice question with options $0$,$1$, $n$ and $n^2$. But clearly $0$ cant be attained, but $0^+$ can be. I guess the question was set keeping integers in mind. @WillJagy But how do I prove it formally (for integral values)? I mean why cant I have $n-1$ or less?

Comment: But the question has never mentioned that $A$ is an integer matrix. I think you are overthinking it.

Comment: @user1551 Yes I guess I am over thinking it. My point being the option for integral values is only available. Since no details are given, we can assume it to be complex (as it covers the rest) and that would tend to $-\infty$ as the answer. And if I consider real entries the answer it tends to $0$(but never attains $0$). So how wrong am I if have written answer as $n$ in the exam.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I will assume all the entries are integers.  By multiplying out the matrices, you see that
$$ \text{trace}(A^TA) = \sum_{i,j} a_{i,j}^2 .$$
Suppose $\text{trace}(A^TA) < n$.  Then at most $n-1$ entries must be non-zero, meaning that at least one column of the matrix is all zeros.  Hence $A$ is not invertible.

Hence $\text{trace}(A^TA) \ge n$.  We know that the value $n$ can be obtained (e.g. by the identity, or any permutation matrix).

Comment: Nice proof by the way. I recently discussed this question with my guide, it is a bit trickier than it seems. Since nothing is said about the entries in $A$, and the trace is the sum of inner products of $i$th row with itself (as Siddharth has pointed out), considering entries as integers, we get the answer to be $n$; considering entries are real, there doesn't exist any minimum (since we can get $\epsilon$, $\epsilon  \rightarrow 0$) and (here is the punch), considering complex entries, we can get $-\infty$. So this question is better suited for a subjective answer than objective.

Comment: Anyhow among the options $0$ can also be achieved (with complex entries). So it comes down to what the question setter thought of while framing this :).

Comment: @Morty, in what possible way doe this question have a «subjective answer»?! That the minimum depends on the field is a quite objective fact.

Comment: @MarianoSuarez-Alvarez I meant that you can check a box since the field is not clear, and the option for the most general field, i.e. complex, is missing.